# Publish ArcSDE FeatureService for Versioned Editing

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, editing

**Scenario**: I need to Publish a data (from ORACLE ArcSDE) for versioned editing. Each user should be able to connect to his version and edit the data throu web application (Silverlight/JAVA/Flex API). 
**Question**: Do I need to create a FeatureService for each user (with ArcMap document containing data from version)? Or is there a simpler way to do it? I would prefer if I have to make only one ArcSDE connection in ArcMap and publish that resource as a featureservice.

Comment: I also have the same problem .. Please help in web editin on particulr version of sde

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: @gaurav Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Please mark this as comment .Its not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One Feature Service is required.

> Creating new versions does not make a
>   copy of the geodatabase. No matter how
>   many geodatabase versions you have,
>   each table and feature class is stored
>   once in the database. The different
>   versions of the geodatabase are
>   tracked in the VERSIONS system table
>   and associated with the records in the
>   adds and deletes tables, as well as
>   with various system tables.

When a new version is created, the owner of the version determines what sort of access to the version is allowed. Possible permissions are as follows:

- Public—Any user may view the version. Any user who has been granted read/write (UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE or read/write) permissions on datasets can modify those datasets.
- Protected—Any user may view the version, but only the owner or the ArcSDE administrator may edit datasets to which he or she has read/write permission.
- Private—Only the owner or the ArcSDE administrator may view the version and modify versioned data.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Geodatabase_version_administration/002n00000054000000/

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. I thought this would be possible in Editing Versioned data in ArcMap. Can I achieve same thing in Web Mapping. Because In ArcMap we make a connection to a version of the database.But in Web Mapping Application, it will publishing a FeatureService (which means publishing an ArcMap document which has got a data from the version). Please correct me if I am getting it wrong.